# Handle Events of Object defined in another class/file

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

I have a VB.NET program where I have multiple forms and some variables that I want to access on all the forms, so I've created a module file that contains some public variables. What I'm finding is that though these variables have been declared `WithEvents`, their events cannot be handled on forms without first copying to a local variable.

Pseudo-Code for what's going on:

In Main.vb (module file)

```
Public WithEvents foo As VarType1
```

In Someform.vb (Windows Form)

```
Private Sub fooEventHandler(sender as System.Object, e As fooEventArgs) Handles foo.fooEvent
```

I get an error that says "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types". Isn't this what I've done? Or am I missing something?

Comment: "defined in the containing type or one of its base types".  It is not of course, it lives in an entirely unrelated module.  You can't use WithEvents/Handles, use the AddHandler statement instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you mean I can add a handler to an event on a in a different module? Or that I would AddHandler in that module pointing at the function in the form?

Comment: I added that to the answer; I didnt include it initally because it prevents VS from knowing how to add the events to the code for you.  It is a little simpler though.

Comment: So glad I found this!!  Was pulling my hair out trying to figure out what I was missing - @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp, thank you for your clear answer!, and Aliden, thank you for asking the question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is the part of the message: `requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type`.  Your `foo` is not **defined in the containing type** (your Form in this case).  There are two ways to do this.

Use the module/global declaration to provide scope foro the Foo object:

```
Public mainFoo As FooBar
```

It really only needs to be `Friend`, but since there is nothing to subscribe to events here, it doesnt need to be `WithEvents`.  Forms/objects which just need access to `Foo` (not the events) can reference this `mainFoo` object.

Next, any form or class which wishes to subscribe to Foo events, does need a local `WithEvents` variable set to the global object:

```
Private WithEvents myFoo As FooBar    ' variable declaration

myFoo = mainFoo       ' set myFoo to reference the real object
```

The advantage to this method is that in the form code, you should be able to select myFoo from the menu on the left, then the FooEvent from the menu on the right for VB/VS to insert the correct event handler as it does with control events:

```
Private Sub myFoo_FooChanged(sender As Object, newFoo As String) _
       Handles myFoo.FooChanged
```

---

This other method is slightly simpler, just use AddHandler to manually hook up that main variable:

```
AddHandler mainFoo.FooChanged, AddressOf sub_FooChanged
```

It prevents having to create a local `WithEvents` variable, but it also prevents VS from creating the Event procedures for you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've actually been using custom events and subs; I just didn't put that correctly in my OP. I'll fix that.

Comment: I know, posted code is often simplified; I had to mention it though for completeness.