# VB.NET Class method handles paint event

Tags: vb.net

How can i use clause Handles in my class method. For example i want to draw an image on picturebox1 with code:

```
Public Class cell
    Public Sub draw_cell() Handles picturebox1.paint
       code
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have an error:

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.
```

How can i do this without using

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
```

ps. sorry for bad english.

Comment: PictureBox1 is a member of your Form class, not a member of your Cell class.  If you want to keep this approach then you'll need a constructor that takes a PictureBox argument and use the AddHandler statement to subscribe the event.  You'd greatly benefit from an introductory book on Windows Forms programming btw, you cannot get very far if you don't know the basics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle Events of Object defined in another class/file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698988/handle-events-of-object-defined-in-another-class-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own routines to draw to your canvas.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim canvas As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
        Dim canvasGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(canvas)
        Dim cellRect As New Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100)
        cell.draw(canvasGraphics, cellRect, Color.Red, New Pen(New SolidBrush(Color.Green), 1))
        PictureBox1.Image = canvas
    End Sub
    Public Class cell
        Public Shared Sub draw(ByRef canvasGraphics As Graphics, ByVal cellRect As Rectangle, ByVal fillColor As Color, ByVal borderPen As Pen)
            Dim renderedCell As New Bitmap(cellRect.Width, cellRect.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
            Dim borderRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, cellRect.Width - 1, cellRect.Height - 1)
            Dim context As BufferedGraphicsContext
            Dim bGfx As BufferedGraphics
            context = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current
            context.MaximumBuffer = New Size(cellRect.Width + 1, cellRect.Height + 1)
            bGfx = context.Allocate(Graphics.FromImage(renderedCell), New Rectangle(0, 0, cellRect.Width, cellRect.Height))
            Dim g As Graphics = bGfx.Graphics
            g.Clear(fillColor)
            g.DrawRectangle(borderPen, borderRect)
            bGfx.Render()
            canvasGraphics.DrawImage(renderedCell, cellRect.Location)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```